# Two generics and infinity

Tags: c#

I have two interfaces. I want to use them for list and for array.

```
public interface IBook<T>
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    T Authors { get; set; }
    int PagesCount { get; set; }
}

public interface IAuthor<T>
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    T Books { get; set; }
}

class Author<T> : IAuthor<IBook<T>[]>
   where T : IAuthor<IBook<T>[]>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IBook<T>[] Books { get; set; }

}
class Book<T> : IBook<IAuthor<T>[]>
   where T : IBook<IAuthor<T>[]>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IAuthor<T>[] Authors { get; set; }
    public int PagesCount { get; set; }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Author<IBook<IAuthor<...>[]>[]> a = new Author<>();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to create object like this in main. The compiler says there are no errors in description of interfaces and classes. Please help me.

Comment: I don't understand your question, can't you just instantiate them as objects or do a list?

Comment: Why do you want/need to use generics here? Also, why are `Books` and `Authors` a `T` instead of a `T[]`? Those names are plurals, after all.

Comment: Create IBookCollection and IAuthorCollection which implements IEnumerable and use it i.e like this: IAuthor<IBookCollection>

Comment: I think you need to reevaluate your strategy. You are getting a lot of double references here.
Why not let the author just keep a list of books and the book an author?

Comment: It has to be many to many relationship

Comment: So what's wrong with an `IBook` that has an `IAuthor[] Authors` property, and an `IAuthor` that has an `IBook[] Books` property? What value do those generic type parameters add? Some sort of categorization? So that cooking books can only have cooking-book authors and sci-fi authors can only write sci-fi books? Does that make sense in your case, and is the type system really the best place to enforce that restriction?

Comment: Simply returning an `IEnumerable<Book>` or `IEnumerable<Author>` would allow you to use `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` if that is what you mean in your question. No need for the masses of Generics here.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think that you may be over-using generics here and making this a little bit more complex than it is.
Evaluate your criteria:

> Author (one -> many) Book
>   Book (one -> many) Author

You can do this by having the following classes:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Author[] Authors { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Book[] Books { get; set; }
}
```

If you make it like this, you can make your life somewhat easier by containing all books and authors within a parent class and using linq queries to identify which object a book / author is related to:

```
public class BookStore
{
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public List<Author> Authors { get; set; }

    public Book GetBook(string name)
    {
        var query = Books.Where(b => b.Name.Equals(name));
        if (query.Count() == 1)
            return query.ElementAt(0);
        else return null;
    }

    public Author GetAuthor(string name)
    {
        var query = Authors.Where(a => a.Name.Equals(name));
        if (query.Count() == 1)
            return query.ElementAt(0);
        else return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would definitely be better for you if you don't use generic classes like this, cause this will be a pain in the neck every time you try to initialise an object. At least you make a default implementation for the generic class where it doesn't need to be given a type of author. You should definitely implement some kind of strategy for your application which will depend on how scalable it should be and easy to maintain and @Nathangrad has given you a great example.

I think your objects should look something like this where your Book's authors are not open to be changed directly and Author's books as well:

```
  public interface IBook
{
    string Name { get; set; }

    ICollection<IAuthor> GetAuthors();

    void AddAuthor(IAuthor book);

    int PagesCount { get; set; }
}

public interface IAuthor
{
    string Name { get; set; }

    ICollection<IBook> GetBooks();

    void AddBook(IBook book);
}

public class Author : IAuthor
{
    private ICollection<IBook> books;

    public Author()
    {
        this.books = new HashSet<IBook>();
    }


    public Author(ICollection<IBook> books)
    {
        this.books = books;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void AddBook(IBook book)
    {
        this.books.Add(book);
    }

    public ICollection<IBook> GetBooks()
    {
        return this.books;
    }
}

public class Book : IBook
{

    private ICollection<IAuthor> authors;

    public Book()
    {
        this.authors = new HashSet<IAuthor>();
    }

    public Book(ICollection<IAuthor> Authors)
    {
        this.authors = Authors;
    }

    public void AddAuthor(IAuthor author)
    {
        this.authors.Add(author);
    }

    public ICollection<IAuthor> GetAuthors()
    {
        return this.authors;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int PagesCount { get; set; }
}
```